# Как вывести значение при принте объекта класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, методы

```
class Any:
    """
    Типа код
    """


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Any()
    print(a) #>>> <__main__.Any object at 0x00000194E371EFD0>
```

Мне нужно чтобы он выводил значение строку или число к примеру.
Есть ли какой-нибудь магический метод?

Comment: Магический метод `__str__`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Существует магический метод `__str__`, который должен возвращать строку

```
class Any:
    """
    Типа код
    """
    def __str__(self):
        return "Типа текст"

print(Any()) #Типа текст
```

но если положить экземпляр в список то метод `__str__` работать не будет.

```
class Any:
    """
    Типа код
    """
    def __str__(self):
        return "Типа текст"

arr = [Any()]
print(arr) #[<__main__.Any object at 0xedc0b580>]
```

Это можно исправить реализовав метод `__repr__`.

```
class Any:
    """
    Типа код
    """
    def __str__(self):
        return "Типа текст"
        
    __repr__ = __str__

arr = [Any()]
print(arr) #[Типа текст]
```